# Value Searching VIA group By

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search

I just took a dive into Mysql, I have following tables:

```
items,table1
```

Items contain `item_name` and `id` and `table1` contain `name`, `item_id` , `value`
Now I have to look browse in such a way that it will give like:

```
name1-item_id-sum(value)
name2-item_id-sum(value)
name3-item_id-sum(value)
name4-item_id-sum(value)
name5-item_id-sum(value)
```

I tried to search double group by but none worked... Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: Just 1 `group by` (not double) is enough here. I'm sure you can do that yourself, cannot you?

Comment: suppose seema has id from 1 to 41 and so does rita and so does all, everyone has id from 1 to 41 now i have to find the sum of value of sima of having id 1, sum of sima having id 2 and so on and after sima, similar happens to rita also..

Comment: don't bother with group by. that's easy point. read up about [JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)s

Comment: ive done this:<br>
SELECT * FROM `table1`,`items` WHERE `table1`.`item_id`=`items`.`id` GROUP BY `table1`.`item_id` limit 0,100;<br> what must i add here?

Comment: u don't sum it `select sum(val) ... `

Comment: if i group by `table1.id` then all the id of seema and rita gets mixed up, how can we not mix up those?

Comment: @sel, you are correct, i just found it out.. anyway thanks

Comment: SELECT SUM(`table1`.`value`) AS value, `table1`.`name`,`items`.`item_name_nepali` FROM `table1`,`items` WHERE `table1`.`item_id`=`items`.`id` GROUP BY `table1`.`item_id`,`table1`.`name` limit 0,100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uhm. I think, this might help.

You don't need to use item table because at the first place, you're not getting any help from it.

```
mysql_query("SELECT name, item_id, SUM(value) FROM table1 GROUP BY item_id, name");
```

ADD: use `ORDER BY name DESC` for much formal result.